# Haskell Define a numeratic type with bounds

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and want to see explore the best practic coding functions with probabilitics distributions.

When coding with probablistic functions, it is typical that a function should return a Float value witin in [0, 1].

Is it possible to define a "Probability" data type that can only take values within that range ?

Thanks very much!

Tao

Comment: The generally accepted approach, I think, is to create an abstract type `newtype Prob = Prob Double` and then have a "smart constructor" which doesn't permit invalid values: `prob :: Double -> Prob; prob x | x <= 1 && x >=0 = Prob x; | otherwise = error ...`

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is not simple. Personally, I would rather use a function like this one:

```
checkBounds :: (Real a, Show a) => a -> a 
checkBounds x | 0 <= x && x <= 1 = x
          | otherwise = error $ show x ++ " is not in [0,1]"
```

But if you want to go further, have a look at this [article](http://www.sohua.xyz/questions-full/222888/how-do-you-use-the-bounded-typeclass-in-haskell-to-define-a-type-with-a-floating), the [probability package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/probability) and this [code snippet](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/16650106/), maybe they could help.